# Google maps - show a map using address on website

Tags: google-maps, geo

I have non working google maps. What could be a problem?

code for get geo cordinates:

```
$gmap = file_get_contents ("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=". urlencode($row['gps']));
$json = json_decode ($gmap);
$suradnice = $json->Placemark[0]->Point->coordinates;
$gps = $s[1] .",". $s[0];
```

embed code:

```
<iframe width='295' height='360' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://maps.google.com/?q={$gps}&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;z=12&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ll={$gps}&amp;output=embed'></iframe>
```

Comment: Does your code to get the coordinates work?  You are using the deprecated v2 geocoding service, see the documentation for the [current version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Answer (score 0):

This process is called "Geocoding". [Here's Google's API for this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services#Geocoding)

Comment: That link is to the deprecated [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services) (only guaranteed to work through May 19, 2013, not recommended for new development)

Comment: Otherwise u can use [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use this version of the Google API as your argument to $file_get_contents, where $lat and $lng are the lattitude and longitude.

"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng&sensor=false"

If you are using an address, do this:

"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$addr&sensor=false"

You can find the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/